# RateLimiting in dotnet 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rate-limiting

I have been implementing RateLimiting in dotnet 7, but when it reaches the limit it blocks all endpoints.  I only want to block the one requested endpoint by the ip user when it get the limit.

This is my code in the Startup file in ConfigureServices:

```
       services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
        {
            options.GlobalLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(content =>
                RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
                    partitionKey: content.Request.Headers.Host.ToString(),
                    factory: partition => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
                    {
                        AutoReplenishment = true,
                        PermitLimit = 5,
                        QueueLimit = 0,
                        Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
                    }
                    ));
            options.RejectionStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests;
        });
```

Comment: Please elaborate the desired behaviour. Do you want each endpoint to have it's own rate limit?

Comment: I think you want to set global limiter and just block the endpoint which be requested to many times in stead of blocking all the endpoint right?

Comment: Guru Stron, what I would like to do is: block the endpoint by the ip user who is breaking the limit.  For example, in my scenario I have 5 request per 20 seconds, if user1 break that rule the endpoint most be limit for him but at the same time if user2 make a request and no rule is break it the request for user2 must be successful.

Comment: Exactly Xinran Shen, but limiting the IP that is requesting the endpoint and break the limit.

Comment: I don't find any solution about how to limit one endpoint which be requested in built-in rate limit middleware, But if you choose to use `AspNetCoreRateLimit`, You can set `EnableEndpointRateLimiting = true` to just limit one endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this ,you can modify your rate limiter implementation to use a per-endpoint rate limiter instead of a global rate limiter.

```
services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.EndpointLimiterFactory = (context, endpointKey) =>
        PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<string, string>(key =>
            RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
                partitionKey: key,
                factory: partition => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    AutoReplenishment = true,
                    PermitLimit = 5,
                    QueueLimit = 0,
                    Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
                })
            )(endpointKey);
    options.RejectionStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests;
});
```

we're using the EndpointLimiterFactory property to create a new PartitionedRateLimiter instance for each endpoint. The endpointKey parameter is used as the partition key for the rate limiter.

With this configuration, each endpoint will have its own rate limiter instance, allowing you to enforce per-endpoint rate limits without blocking all endpoints when the rate limit is exceeded for a specific endpoint.

Comment: There's an error: 'RateLimiterOptions' does not contain a definition for 'EndPointLimiterFactory'.

Comment: User the "PartitionedRateLimiter" instead of the "EndpointLimiterFactory "